# invalid syntax - python

Tags: python, syntax, if-statement

I have a set of arguments and all of their dest is 'search_and', 'search_not', 'search_start', 'search_then', and 'filename'

The code that I have to catch the error is

```
    if ( options.filename is None) and ( (options.search_and is None) or  (options.search_not is None) or (options.search_start is None) or (options.search_then is None):
        parser.error(usage)
        sys.exit()
```

It may seem like a silly mistake, can someone tell me what is going on?

EDIT#1:
I added the ')' at the end to make sure it closes properly but it still says invalid syntax.

```
    if ( options.filename is None) and ( (options.search_and is None) or  (options.search_not is None) or (options.search_start is None) or (options.search_then is None)):
```

EDIT#2:
Here is what I have so far.

```
    import optparse from OptionParser
    usage = "useage: %prog [options]"
    parser = OptionParser(usage)
    parser.add_option("-a", "--all", type="string", dest="search_and", help="find ALL lines in the file for the word1 AND word2")
    parser.add_option("-b", "--all", type="string", dest="search_not", help="search and find the lines that contain words1 not word2")
    parser.add_option("-c", "--all", type="string", dest="search_start", help="search and find a line that starts with word1 or word2")
    parser.add_option("-d", "--all", type="string", dest="search_then", help="search and find a line that has word1 followed by word2")
    parser.add_option("-f", "--file", type="string", dest="filename", help="file name"

    if ( options.filename is None) and ( (options.search_and is None) or  (options.search_not is None) or (options.search_start is None) or (options.search_then is None)):
```

After the code is run by:
python script.py -a hi bye

I get invalid syntax with the if statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line before the if statement

```
parser.add_option("-f", "--file", type="string", dest="filename", help="file name"
```

does not have a closing ).

Python interpreter usually complains about such syntax errors in next line.So, if you get a syntax error at any line, it is advisable to check the preceding line as well

Answer (score 1):

This is equivalent to what you're trying to do, and may be *slightly* more readable

```
if options.filename is None and None in [options.search_and, options.search_not, options.search_start, options.search_then]:
  parser.error(usage)
  sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed a `)` before the `:`. Your editor should be catching these sort of mistakes.

Comment: That's because you did the same sort of error (unbalanced brackets) elsewhere.

Comment: Vazques-Abrams, I'll add what i have so far for the code. at edit#2 of the original post, give me a minute.

Comment: I just don't see it. I'm constantly rewriting it but its just not working lol.

Comment: @ino: now you missed a `)` before `if`

Comment: Still missing a ) at the end; should be: `if options.filename is None and ((options.search_and is None) or  (options.search_not is None) or (options.search_start is None) or (options.search_then is None)):

Comment: @Furbeenator: Yes, that's what I wrote.

Answer (score 0):

`if options.filename is None and ((options.search_and is None) or (options.search_not is None) or (options.search_start is None) or (options.search_then is None))`

Comment: Well then why "@Furbeenator: Yes, that's what I wrote.?"

Answer (score 0):

In your original statement, "( options.filename is None)" you should remove the last ")" make replace that code with:

```
 (options.filename is None
```

That should fix your syntax error.